# Эродированный или эрозированный

Tags: словообразование

Прилагательное от эрозия - эродированный ("эродированная почва").
Постоянно читаю у разных (но молодых) авторов эрозированный.

Всё бы ничего, но с каждым разом становится все труднее доказывать очевидное.

Есть ли у формы "эрозированый" хоть какие-то шансы быть признанной?

Уточняю. Историю и теорию я знаю, а что не знаю - не слишком сейчас важно.  Мне нужно в чисто практических целях уяснить, могу ли я пропустить вариант "эрозивный", ибо сражаться уже нет сил. Я не корректор, просто вычитываю статьи в роли вольнонаёмного работника.

Comment: В каком контексте у вас "эрозивный"? Мне встречался только в медицинском аспекте.

Comment: Я же написала. Почвы.

Comment: **Терминология ГОСТ 26640-85: Земли. Термины и определения**
10. Эродированные земли
Земли, потерявшие в результате эрозии частично или полностью плодородный слой почвы

http://normative_reference_dictionary.academic.ru/92425/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2_26640-85%3A_%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8._%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B_%D0%B8_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: И это я знаю. Спасибо.

Comment: "Шансы" есть у любого повального увлечения на любое изменение в языке. Даже у возникшей лет пять назад манеры употребления слов "в том числе", которая до этого считалась вопиюще безграмотной. Каждый сам решает, участвовать в таком новшестве или посопротивляться.

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения логики переноса терминов из английского, возможны разные способы образования производных терминов:

1) образование от перенесённого существительного добавлением русских суффиксов;

2) образование с учётом отличий в суффиксах у производных терминов в исходном языке (если они различаются у разных частей речи).

Традиция употребления терминов в пользу того или иного варианта складывается по-разному, но если возникают разночтения и нужно прийти к единому варианту, то приходится искать обоснование с учётом особенностей языка источника (как это происходило напр. с вариантами "имплант -> имплантат" - через немецкий язык как источник). В данном случае "*эрод(з)ированный*" - не совсем прилагательное, по форме это *причастие*, образованное от глагола "**эродировать**" (подвергуться эрозии). От существительного же "эрозия" (**erosion**) пришлось бы сначала образовать глагол "эрозировать", но в английском слова с соотв. суффиксом - **erose** и **erosive** - прилагательные, а не глаголы (**to erode**). Соотв. русские прилагательные образованы в виде "**эрозийный**" (вызывающий эрозию) и **эрозионный** (вызванный эрозией или связанный с ней), есть и прилагательное "**эрозивный**", заимствованное через прилагательное *erosive* (связанный с эрозией) и закрепившееся в медицинской терминологии. Такое обилие вариантов русского прилагательного, которые не противоречат исходным английским (не заимствуют суффикс из другой части речи), делает желательным выбор в пользу одного варианта (родственного по смыслу) причастия, причём для выбора варианта "**эродированный**" есть основание: заимствование верного глагольного суффикса.

Comment: В русском языке глаголы с помощью суффикса ИРОВА  образуются от существительных: асфальт - асфальтировать (наделять или покрывать тем, что названо мотивирующим существительным, но не глаголом).   И вообще, целое семейство слов имеет общий корень, а одно слово явно выпадает из него.  Сразу хочется спросить: у нас что, есть чередование З/Д в корне?

Comment: _(малорегулярные чередования)
э)|т' – с'|, |т – з'|, |д – з'| и |д' – з'| чередуются перед тем же суф. морфом -и|j|- в случаях дискутировать – дискуссия, поэт – поэзия, эродировать – эрозия, претендовать – претензия; |д'| чередуется с |з| и |з'| в случаях телевидение – телевиз-ор и телевиз-ионный; |з' – ц| в случае претензия – претенц-иозный;_

http://rusgram.narod.ru/1095-1110.html

Comment: *(малорегулярные чередования)* - Да, это все правда про чередования. И тема эта хорошо проработана. Но вопрос у меня не по этой части.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще говоря, вариант "эрозия ― эрозировать ― эрозированный" **более понятен**, чем "эрозия ― эродировать ― эродированный".

**Слово "эрозия" известно в русском языке с начала 20 века**, оно заимствовано через французский (еrosion) или немецкий (Erosion) от лат. **erosio ― разъедаю, erodere ― разъедать**).

Получается. что глагол  "эродировать" образован от основы латинского глагола с помощью суффикса ИРОВА, который обычно используется **при образовании глаголов от существительных.**

Поэтому весьма возможно, что "эрозированный" будет использоваться в языке, и даже уже используется не только в научной, но и в художественной литературе, например:

Шершавый воздух, разводя челюсти, проталкивается в рот, перекрывает, забивает дыхание, закупоривает уши. Бурая **эрозированная** поверхность Эдема ― наотмашь. [Александр Гаррос, Алексей Евдокимов. [Голово]ломка (2001)]

**Дополнение**

Если посмотреть в Google, то вариант "эрозированная почва" используется **так часто, что его пора вводить в словари**, например: "К основным рекомендациям относятся следующие: в первую очередь необходимо вносить осадки на почвы истощенные, **эрозированные**" (из "Справочник химика").

Comment: "оно заимствовано.....от лат. erosio ― разъедаю, erodere ― разъедать." ------------- это я всё знаю. Вопрос-то в том, что даже на бытовом уровне "эрозированный" словари не дозволяют. А тут - научный стиль. Устала уже бороться.

Comment: Всё меняется, и словари тоже.  Разве это нормально, что без латыни однокоренные слова не определяются на слух? Непонятно, почему вообще был сделан выбор в пользу глагола  "эродировать", может быть, это ошибка, которую надо исправить?

Comment: Ирина, уточните пожалуйста против чего конкретно Вы возражаете: "эрозивный" или "эрозированный" или против того и другого вместе. Со вторым вроде бы всё ясно: словарь. Давайте теперь сосредоточимся на первом.